# facing issue when im executing my query in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

when i execute my query in sql its working fine
but when i execute it in sybase it gives me an error
Error: near line 1: in prepare, near "(": syntax error (1)
i searched about it what i reach is that Sybase ASE does not support **ROW_NUMBER()**

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(',' + '145,144,84,85' + ',',
        Numbers.N + 1,
        CHARINDEX(',', ',' + '145,144,84,85' + ',', Numbers.N + 1) - Numbers.N - 1) AS ABC
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (LEN('145,144,84,85')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N
    FROM sys.syscolumns AS c1
    CROSS JOIN sys.syscolumns AS c2
) AS Numbers
WHERE SUBSTRING(',' + '145,144,84,85' + ',', Numbers.N, 1) = ','
```

i want my query to work for both MSSQL server and sybase
i appreciate ur help thanks

i tried to do it with too many ways but i didnt get a solution

for oracle the query that im using is

```sql
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR(USR_APP_IDS,'[^,]+', 1, N) ABC
  FROM  OC_APP_CUSTOMER_GROUP, (select level n from dual connect by level < 200) where n <= regexp_count(USR_APP_IDS,',')+1
```

Comment: 'to work for both _sql_ and sybase'? SQL is a language defined by ISO/ANSI. Perhaps you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: yes i mean for MS SQL server

Comment: please update the question with a textual description of what you're trying to do; and, you are correct, Sybase ASE does not have support for window functions; also fwiw .... `sys.syscolumns` is not going to work in ASE (the correct reference is going to be `syscolumns` or `dbo.syscolumns`), then again, it looks like you're just using `syscolumns` as a means of generating a series of numbers .... ???

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  USR_APP_IDS
  FROM  OC_APP_CUSTOMER_GROUP
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  1 AS @rownum
  ) AS R
  WHERE  @rownum <= regexp_count(USR_APP_IDS,',')+1
```

`cross join` to join the `OC_APP_CUSTOMER_GROUP` table with a `temporary table` that contains a single row with a value of 1 in the `@rownum` column. The `WHERE` clause then filters the rows so that only rows where the value of the `@rownum` column is less than or equal to the number of comma-separated values in the `USR_APP_IDS` column.